# Rails ajax response collection_select not populating properly

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In the rails app, I am making an ajax request to get the options for collection_select. I am able to receive the response but when the same is updated on the html body, the collection_select dropdown shows the values with entries along with "</option>\n". I believe the response from the server is fine but maybe I am missing something on the client end.

How can this be rectified? The response received from the server is

```
$("#filter_user_course").empty().append("<option value=\"7\">KidsCourse<\/option>\n<option value=\"6\">TestCourse1<\/option>\n<option value=\"8\">QuizTest<\/option>");
```

The client end JS code is here `$.get("getSampleList",$("#filter_example").serialize(), function(data) { console.log(data); $("#filter_target").html(data)}, "script");`

This is the code on the rails server side that generates the ajax response `<% resp = escape_javascript(options_from_collection_for_select(@books, :id, :title)) %>
$("#filter_user_course").empty().append("<%= resp.html_safe %>");`

[image: The collection_select entries]

Comment: Try `$("#filter_user_course").empty().append("<option value=\"7\">KidsCourse<\/option>\n<option value=\"6\">TestCourse1<\/option>\n<option value=\"8\">QuizTest<\/option>").html_safe;`

Comment: @Pavan - it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try this `$("#filter_user_course").empty().append("<option value=\"7\">KidsCourse<\/option>\n<option value=\"6\">TestCourse1<\/option>\n<option value=\"8\">QuizTest<\/option>".html_safe);`

Comment: @Pavan - I edited the question to add the rails server end code that generates the html ajax response. This change also didn't help. This HTML snippet is generated by the rails js code.